# Converting plain JS to React.js using useRef hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I tried to convert this plain javascript to react using useRef hook.

Plain JS:
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-maxwell-ub18w?file=/src/index.js

React: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-frog-urzjp?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const fileElem = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        id="fileElem"
        multiple
        accept="image/*"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
      />
      <button onClick={() => fileElem.current.click()}>
        Select some files
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why useRef is not working with `fileElem.current.click()`? What did I do wrong here?
Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Please post relevant code in your question/issue (in addition to the links), with appropriate reproduction steps, if necessary. [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your input instead of using `id='fileElem'` use `ref={fileElem}` and it should work fine.

That's how we do it in React.

Answer (score 1):

Change `fileElem.current.click()` to `fileElem.current.click`. With the parentheses you are **calling** the click function on the ref which causes it to be immediately clicked and then assigning the return value to the `onClick` handler of the React element. Instead you want to assign the click handler of `fileElem` to the click handler of the React element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ref={fileElem}` and `type="file"`, as shown below:

```
<input
  type="file"
  ref={fileElem}
  multiple
  accept="image/*"
  style={{ display: 'none' }}
/>
<button onClick={() => fileElem.current.click()}>
  Select some files
</button>
```

Check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for how to use `ref`.